# Using MySQL how can I better select all people and their jobs excluding anyone who has a particular job?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a link to a fiddle that currently works, it just seems like there is a better way to do this that I am not seeing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/396f2/6

```
--- Sample schema
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `people_jobs` (
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `jid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`,`jid`),
  KEY `jid` (`jid`),
  CONSTRAINT `people_jobs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `people` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `people_jobs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`jid`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`id`)
);
```

And here is the query

```
SELECT p.name, j.title FROM people p LEFT JOIN
 people_jobs pj ON pj.pid = p.id LEFT JOIN
 jobs j ON j.id = pj.jid WHERE p.id NOT IN
(SELECT p.id FROM people p INNER JOIN
 people_jobs pj ON pj.pid = p.id INNER JOIN
 jobs j ON j.id = pj.jid WHERE j.title = 'Artist');
```

Is there a way to do this with a LEFT JOIN? That is how I would typically look for things that don't exist in a table. But in this case I am looking for things that don't exist or don't match a particular job. I poked around a lot but could not find any examples of excluding based on not being in a table or matching a particular condition.

I want to get back pairs of people and their associated jobs (or null if they have no jobs) who are not Artists. So if someone has 5 jobs, but one of them is 'Artist' I want to exclude that person entirely from the list.

Comment: Perhaps you can compare a count of all jobs with a count of all jobs not matching (or not matching) certain criteria. The unwanted rows will have different counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the result set you want (people to people_jobs to jobs), then left join to `people_jobs` a second time, where the person is the same but the job is always "artist".  Filter out the resulting non-null rows, because those are people who have an artist job.

e.g.

```
SELECT p.name, j.title
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN (
    people_jobs pj
    JOIN jobs j ON j.id = pj.jid
) ON pj.pid = p.id
LEFT JOIN people_jobs artists ON artists.pid = p.id AND artists.jid = 5
WHERE artists.pid IS NULL
```

This assumes you know (or can get) the job id for an artist ahead of time, and that it's `5`.  If not, you can do another nested join or subquery to look up the job by name.

Comment: @beny23 ah, pardon.  need some more lefts.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure on how you would be using your query without a nested sub query to exclude artists, but a small optimisation would be to remove the unnecessary join to people in your sub query, I.e.

```
SELECT p.name, j.title 
  FROM people p 
  LEFT JOIN people_jobs pj ON pj.pid = p.id 
  LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.id = pj.jid 
 WHERE p.id NOT IN
   (SELECT pj.pid 
      FROM people_jobs pj 
     INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.id = pj.jid 
     WHERE j.title = 'Artist')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this:

```
select
  p.name, j.title
from
  people as p
  left join people_jobs as pj on p.id = pj.pid
  left join jobs as j on j.id = pj.jid
  left join (
    select 
      p.Id
    from
      people as p
      inner join people_jobs pj on p.id = pj.pid
      inner join jobs as j on pj.jid = j.id
    where
      j.title = 'Artist'
  ) as a on p.id = a.id
where
  a.id is null;
```

You can put the condition in a `left join`instead of a `where`condition.

Try [the (new) updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/396f2/45).

If your tables are large, maybe you can consider creating a temp table and using it instead of the subquery:

```
drop table if exists temp_condition;
create temporary table temp_condition
    select distinct
      p.Id
    from
      people as p
      inner join people_jobs pj on p.id = pj.pid
      inner join jobs as j on pj.jid = j.id
    where
      j.title = 'Artist';
alter table temp_condition
    add unique index idx_id(Id);
select
  p.name, j.title
from
  people as p
  left join people_jobs as pj on p.id = pj.pid
  left join jobs as j on j.id = pj.jid
  left join temp_condition as a on p.id = a.id
where
  a.id is null;
```

Hope this helps now

Comment: this will only filter out the (people, job) pairs where the job is artist, not all pairs that include an artist.